# jQuery form submit without refresh

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I'd like to have the data submit however not refresh the page. I've added this code which stops the refresh but has also stopped the submit. Is there a way to do this when using preventDefault()?

```
    $("editUserForm").on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $("editUserForm").serialize()

                })

            });
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: If this is the actual selector then this script does exactly nothing

Comment: `$("editUserForm")` make sure the selector is correct.

Comment: @j08691 no errors in the console

Comment: what is "editUserForm" is this a form name?

Comment: @RanaGhosh yes it is

Comment: just return false in the function (or if that doesn't work change type of the submit button in the form to 'button' and use onclick event)

Comment: The previously posted answer allowed the submit, however the page refreshed

Comment: you want the form to validate or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector will only select elements of the type `editUserForm`, as in:

```
<editUserForm></editUserForm>
```

You probably meant to select the form either [by its id](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

```
$("#editUserForm")

<form id="editUserForm"></form>
```

or [by its name attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("form[name='editUserForm']")

<form name="editUserForm"></form>
```

Comment: With the wrong selector the script won't have any effect. But: "_I've added this code which stops the refresh but has also stopped the submit_". Hence this can't be the problem here.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, this is definitely only part of the problem. Could be a typo, but since it's repeated a second time I doubt that. I think the OP is very confused, but I can only address the issues that are apparent in the question.

Comment: @JDB my selectors seem to be sound. If I remove preventDefault the form submits. Form id and name are both editUserForm

Comment: @ChrisR Try running your selector in the developer console and see what is returned. I can't explain why your selector would work, unless you are not using jQuery. Without a prefix, that selector will only select elements by tag name. See https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to submit form using ajax without refresh page.

```
                <form name="addstudent" id="addstudent" action="add.php" method="post">

                    <fieldset><legend>Add student to tutoring list</legend>
                    <div><label for="studentid">ID number</label><input type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid"></div>


                    <div><label for="assignment">Tutoring assignment</label><select name="assignment" id="assignment">
                    <option value="">Please select an assignment</option>
                    <option value="att">Activity Time</option>
                    <option value="acc">ACC</option>
                    <option value="tech">ACC Tech </option>
                    <option value="ast">After School</option>
                    </select></div>

                    <div><label for="teacher">Assigning teacher</label><input type="text" name="teacher" id="teacher"></div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        $("body").on('submit',"#addstudent" ,function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: $( '#addstudent' ).attr( 'action' ),
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: $("#addstudent").serialize(),
                                success: function(data) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                      });      

                    </script>
```